# Setting up a user and token authentication in Laravel 10.x with Laravel Sanctum

Tags: laravel, authentication, openapi

I'm trying to set up a basic user login system in Laravel, but I just can't get it right. It's probably simply that I'm not quite understanding how it all works together, so hopefully someone can help me.

The goal is simple: Have a way for my users to log in, get some kind of token, and based on that token get their user data so I can see who's doing the requests etc.

I have a UserController as follows:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\Card;
use App\Models\CardBulletpoint;
use App\Models\CardData;
use App\Models\Edit;
use App\Models\EditData;
use App\Models\Enums\FactionEnum;
use Illuminate\Validation\Rules\Enum;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Models\User;
use App\Models\UserData;
use Illuminate\Auth\Events\Registered;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Illuminate\Validation\Rules;
use App\Http\Requests\Auth\LoginRequest;

class UserController extends Controller
{
    public function index(Request $request)
    {
        return $request->user();
    }

    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:' . User::class],
            'password' => ['required', 'confirmed', Rules\Password::defaults()],
        ]);

        $user = User::create([
            'name' => $request->name,
            'email' => $request->email,
            'password' => Hash::make($request->password),
            'api_token' => Str::random(60),
        ]);

        event(new Registered($user));

        Auth::login($user);

        $token = $request->user()->createToken($request->token_name);
 
        return ['token' => $token->plainTextToken];
    }

    public function update(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:' . User::class],
            'password' => ['required', 'confirmed', Rules\Password::defaults()],
        ]);

        $user = $request->user();
        $user->name = $request->name;
        $user->email = $request->email;
        $user->password = $request->password;
        $user->save();
        return $user;
    }

    public function login(LoginRequest $request)
    {
        $request->authenticate();

        $token = $request->user()->createToken("testtoken");
 
        return ['token' => $token->plainTextToken];
    }
}
```

And I have a routes/api.php as follows:

```
Route::middleware('guest')->group(function () {
    Route::post('register', [UserController::class, 'store']);
    Route::post('login', [UserController::class, 'login']);
});

Route::middleware('auth:sanctum')->group(function () {
    Route::get('user', [UserController::class, 'index']);
    Route::put('update', [UserController::class, 'update']);
});
```

I also changed the auth.php as follows:

```
    'defaults' => [
        'guard' => 'api',
        'passwords' => 'users',
    ],
    'guards' => [
        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
    ],
```

And updated the sanctum.php:

```
    'guard' => ['api'],
```

I'm also using dedoc/scramble to easily see and execute my requests.

The current issue is that the user and update functions don't show to accept a token, and if I call them they just immediately return a 401.

I'm probably either mixing up different authentication methods, not using the right functions at the right time, and it could even be that I'm using something that's not supported by the documentation. In any case, any help or alternative solutions would be appreciated.

Comment: Please go through this simple official [doc](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/sanctum) and you'll achieve exactly what you need.

Comment: The 'simple' official doc got me where I am.

Answer (score 1):

In the end, the code itself was working, it was just the Scramble documentation which didn't pick up on the authentication automatically.

You can add it in the AppServiceProvider.php:

```
public function boot(): void
{
    Scramble::extendOpenApi(function (OpenApi $openApi) {
        $openApi->secure(
            SecurityScheme::http('bearer', 'JWT')
        );
    });
}
```

That allows you in the OpenAPI front-end to fill in the bearer token and everything works after that.